# How to show different images based on the content of a WP shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I have a shortcode from a plugin: [movie_certification label="no"]

Based on its content I want to show a different image though a php if statement. I can't seem to get it to work.

If anybody could help me with this (newbie) question it would be very appreciated.

This is what it should do:

- if [movie_certification label="no"] == var1 then
- or [movie_certification label="no"] == var2 then
- or [movie_certification label="no"] == var3 then
- or [movie_certification label="no"] == var4 then

if none of the conditions are met: do nothing (don't show anything)

Kind regards!
Roland

Comment: Shortcodes are processed by function handlers that return HTML/text content, you can't use the result in PHP the way you are trying. If you want to use the existing shortcode you could try to do it with JavaScript client side, but the best bet would be to write your own short code handler to do it.

Comment: OK, thnx. 

The result of the shortcode is also echoed on the page. (in a specific class) is there any way to use the echoed result?

Comment: Where do you want to output that result? Do you want to change the shortcode's output directly or  you want to output that images somewhere else? Please, provide more background, like links to the site, code, what did you tried to do to solve the problem etc.